# Memory game flipping individual cards isn't working - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, foreach

I've created a memory game. Most of the functions work, but one thing I'm struggling with is getting the cards to flip correctly. Here is the function I'm using to swap between the back of the card (`card.jpg`) and the front of the card (image names found in the `ImagesArr` array):

```
// Swap out cards for shuffled images
function swapImages() {
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].src !== "/img/card.jpg") {
      images[i].src = imagesArr[i];
    } else {
      images[i].src = "/img/card.jpg";
    }
  }
}
```

It works to show the hidden images, but it shows ALL of them, not just the one that's clicked. I also have this function above it which helps with the flip animation and adding some necessary classes as well as calling the swapImages function.

```
// Flip the cards over on click and start the timer
function flipCards() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
      card.classList.toggle("flipped");
      card.classList.toggle("chosen");
      chosenCards.push(card);
      startTimer();
      swapImages();
      checkMatch();
    });
  });
}
```

I feel like I need a `forEach` loop or something like that, but I'm not sure how to implement it or where to implement it. I also could be completely wrong and don't need a `forEach` loop at all. TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use target event (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp). So that program know which card is on other side .By the code that you provided l suspect that on click all cards flip.

Comment: You're on to something. I definitely made some progress by adding a target event, but I'm still not quite there.

Comment: Can you post you code on jsFiddle or here. So that l can see all code.

Comment: Here is a link to the project in jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/redliz5808/a205ur8h/9/